# Linux/Fedora/Gnome disable "Press or click a key to unlock" for fast fingerprint login

Tags: fedora, gnome, fingerprint

I'm running Fedora 36 with GNOME DE and I'm trying to disable the need to press a key on the lock screen, so that I can just press Power/Fingerprint button and the laptop unlocks. I've already tried the "Automatic login" function but that disables the authentication part completely which is not what i want.

Thank you in advance for your help.